Problem export Auto Smooth .glb/.gltf
I have a problem with the display of smooth/auto smooth when I export my object in .glb/.gltf, this is not taken into consideration.
I tried everything... putting the modifier "smooth by angle" then putting "apply modifier" in the export settings doesn't change anything.
For information, I export the 3D model to Twinmotion.
In .fbx it works but I need the .glb/gltf format



Will it work if you apply mesh modifiers by hand? If so, you might need to report this issue to the glTF addon developers.
Also, there is an alternative glTF exporter which comes with Verge 3D. You might check it out as well.
